# How to remove tables from disk space when posrgresql is out of memory and not running

Tags: database, postgresql, psql

How to remove particular database tables from disk storage when posrgresql is out of memory and not running?
I can not connect via pg_admin nor psql.

I get:

```
psql: error: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

So I can not use SQL queries. What would be the best action in your opinion?

Comment: What error do you get when you try to start the server?

Comment: You will need to increase the disk space. Never manually delete any files from the data directory.